# T-SQL row level validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have above table name as reservation. Now I need to validate if difference is  DifferentalrCost (D) column is correct. As you can see I can validate manual but how can I do in large scale. Basically, column D represent the difference between column C rows.  Is there any way I can validate as true statement. Can someone help me with quarry.

[image]

Validate as true statement for column D if possible or any logic for validation.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Here's a link on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please don't use images, not everyone can see them, can't copy/paste text, etc.  You also need to clarify what you are actually trying to do.  Sample data, desired results, etc.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Do you want to see differentialcost as Cost - CostPreviousRow? Or even ABS(Cost - CostPreviousRow) ?

Comment: @siggemannen i want to see if the value in column D is correct or not, i think Lead function is used to create column D, basically its upper row - bellow row of column C

Comment: What you describe isn't row-level validation. You're calculating values among multiple rows. It's unclear what you want to do too. Is `differentialcost` a stored value? Are you trying to see if the stored value is correct? You can use `Cost -LAG(Cost) OVER(ORDER BY ReservationID, EffectiveDate)` to calculate that value. That probably replicates how the value was calculated in the first place. Or you can calculate the running total of `DifferentialCost` to see if it's the same as Cost. That's probably `SUM(DifferentialCost) OVER(Order BY ReservationID, EffectiveDate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on great work for @PatrickHurst, I'm going to present an alternative way to check the values:

```sql
DECLARE @Example TABLE (ReservationID BIGINT, EffectiveDate DATETIME, Cost DECIMAL(10,3), DifferentialCost DECIMAL(10,3));
INSERT INTO @Example (ReservationID, EffectiveDate, Cost, DifferentialCost) VALUES
(121824, '2021-05-15', 0,       0), (121824, '2021-05-16', 80,      80),
(121824, '2021-05-20', 80,      0), (121824, '2021-05-26', 98.12,   18.12);


SELECT  e.*
,   e.Cost - ISNULL(x.cost, 0) AS CheckCost
FROM    @Example e
OUTER apply (
    SELECT  TOP 1 ex2.cost
    FROM    @example ex2
    WHERE   ex2.reservationid = e.reservationid
    AND ex2.effectivedate < e.effectivedate
    ORDER BY ex2.effectivedate DESC
    ) x
--where e.Cost - ISNULL(x.cost, 0)<> DifferentialCost
```

This retreives the previous row by an outer apply per reservationid and then subtracts it from the Cost-column.
You can uncomment the WHERE to find the rows that has "problems" i.e. diffs.

One problem is if you have multiple duplicate dates, then you need some sort of tie-breaker to get the sort correct

Answer (score 3):

You've been lectured in the comments about providing the example DDL/DML, so I won't do it again.

```
DECLARE @Example TABLE (ReservationID BIGINT, EffectiveDate DATETIME, Cost DECIMAL(10,3), DifferentialCost DECIMAL(10,3));
INSERT INTO @Example (ReservationID, EffectiveDate, Cost, DifferentialCost) VALUES
(121824, '2021-05-15', 0,       0), (121824, '2021-05-15', 80,      80),
(121824, '2021-05-20', 80,      0), (121824, '2021-05-26', 98.12,   18.12);
```

Using this example data, taken from your image, we can use the `LAG` function:

```
SELECT *, Cost-COALESCE(LAG(Cost,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ReservationID ORDER BY EffectiveDate),0) AS CalculatedDifferentialCost
  FROM @Example
```

| ReservationID | EffectiveDate | Cost | DifferentialCost | CalculatedDifferentialCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121824 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
| 121824 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00.000 | 80.000 | 80.000 | 80.000 |
| 121824 | 2021-05-20 00:00:00.000 | 80.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
| 121824 | 2021-05-26 00:00:00.000 | 98.120 | 18.120 | 18.120 |

All we're doing here is using `LAG` to look back 1 row, and then compare that to the current row to produce the difference. The `OVER` clause of a windowed function defines what the window will use, in this case we want to `PARTITION` (or group by) the `ReservationID` column and `ORDER` by the `EffectiveDate` column.